# Filter number of orders in each month from given array data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following data object. Each record contains order value and month of order. My objective here is to count how many orders per month have been ordered.

```
const data = [{
  order: "a",
  date: "Jan"
}, {
  order: "b",
  date: "Jan"
}, {
  order: "c",
  date: "Feb"
}]
```

So in the above code in `Jan`  there are **two** orders, **one** orders in `Feb` **and** no orders for the rest of the months. So for the months which have no orders will have `0` value.

The expected output will be (array format)

```
orders = [{"Jan":2},
          {"Feb":1},
          {"Mar":0},
          {"Apr":0},
          {"Jun":0},
          {"Jul":0},
          {"Aug":0},
          {"Sept":0},
          {"Oct":0},
          {"Nov":0},
          {"Dec":0}]
```

Here is the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-mahavira-k7kths?file=/src/App.js:24-157) .

Comment: What did you try to solve this yourself?

Comment: [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is your friend in this case.

Comment: this format ain't good, it's basically an array of dictionaries all with just a single entry, and every time you want to use these items you first have to find out what the correct property is. Make it a consistent format, either one object per year `{Jan:2,Feb:1,Mar:0,Apr:0,Jun:0,Jul:0,Aug:0,Sept:0,Oct:0,Nov:0,Dec:0}` or identical objects for each month `[{month:"Jan", count:2},{month:"Feb", count:1},...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects) the `date`
2. `map()` over each month, set to the grouped value, or `0` as fallback

```js
const data = [{order: "a", date: "Jan"}, {order: "b", date: "Jan"}, {order: "c", date: "Feb"}];

const grouped = data.reduce((p, c) => {
    p[c.date] = (p[c.date] || 0) + 1;
    return p;
}, {})

const result = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ]
  .map(m => ({ [m]: grouped[m] || 0 }));

console.log(result);
```

Result:

```json
[
  {
    "Jan": 2
  },
  {
    "Feb": 1
  },
  {
    "Mar": 0
  },
  {
    "Apr": 0
  },
  {
    "May": 0
  },
  {
    "Jun": 0
  },
  {
    "Jul": 0
  },
  {
    "Aug": 0
  },
  {
    "Sep": 0
  },
  {
    "Oct": 0
  },
  {
    "Nov": 0
  },
  {
    "Dec": 0
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of Array.reduce and Array.map to achieve this quite easily, and in a quite readable manner:

```js
const data = [{
  order: "a",
  date: "Jan"
}, {
  order: "b",
  date: "Jan"
}, {
  order: "c",
  date: "Feb"
}]

// A helper array containing all months
const months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March'] // ... and so on

// create an object with keys being month name and value being number of orders during that month
const monthsWithOrders = data.reduce((allOrders, currentOrder) => {
  if (allOrders[currentOrder.date]) {
    allOrders[currentOrder.date] += 1
  } else {
    allOrders[currentOrder.date] = 1
  }

  return allOrders
}, {})

// create an array with an oject for each month
const result = months.map(month => {
  return {
    [month]: monthsWithOrders[month] || 0
  }
})

console.log(result)

// results will be:
// [{
//     "Jan": 2
//   },
//   {
//     "Feb": 1
//   },
//   {
//     "March": 0
//   }
// ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it with a `reduce` function:

```js
const data = [
    {
       order: "a",
       date: "Jan"
    }, 
    {
       order: "b",
       date: "Jan"
    }, 
    {
       order: "c",
       date: "Feb"
    }
];

const weeks = ["Jan", "Feb", "May"];
const mappedWeeks = weeks.reduce((total, week) => 
      ([
        ...total,
        {
           [week]: data.filter(({ date }) => date === week).length 
        }
      ]), []);

console.log(mappedWeeks);
```